# Can i store static API Key in php file safely

Tags: php, android, api

i want to use FCM in my android application , and i was wondering what is the best practice to store a static API such as Server Key API of FCM .

And after a lot o reading i found that even using ProGard doesn't save the API securely, so the conclusion is to never store keys in the app source code .

My solution is to save the key in a .php file like this, so that every time a device send a notification it sends data ( Notification title , message .. ) to my server that contain the server key and redirect the request to *https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send*

**My php file :**

```
<?php

    require_once __DIR__ . '/notification.php';
    $notification = new Notification();

    $title = "Notification Title";
    $message = "Notification Message";


    $notification->setTitle($title);
    $notification->setMessage($message);


    $firebase_api = "API_STATIC_SERVER_CODE_THAT_I_NEED_TO_HIDE";


    $requestData = $notification->getNotificatin();

    $fields = array(
        'to' => '/topics/Test_Topic',
        'data' => $requestData,
    );



    $url = 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';

    $headers = array(
        'Authorization: key=' . $firebase_api,
        'Content-Type: application/json'
    );

    // Open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarily
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));

    // Execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if($result === FALSE){
        die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
    }

    // Close connection
    curl_close($ch);

    echo '<h2>Result</h2><hr/><h3>Request </h3><p><pre>';
    echo json_encode($fields,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
    echo '</pre></p><h3>Response </h3><p><pre>';
    echo $result;
    echo '</pre></p>';

?>
```

But, is that safe ? Could hackers some how download my php content ( without hacking my server ) , or the fact that i am using HTTPS connections keeps my data safe .

And what else can i do if it's not safe enough

Thank you